# Performing periodic audits and best practice

Tags: c#

I'm doing a windows form and would like an audit task to happen every 30 seconds.  This audit is essentially checking a series of services on remote computers and reporting back into a richtextbox the status.

Current I have this running in an endless background thread and using an invoker to update the richtextbox in the main form.

Is this best practice?  If I made an endless loop in my main form that would prevent any of my buttons from working, correct?

I'm just curious if every time I want to create a periodic audit check I have to create a new thread which checks the status or file or what have you?

Edit: I looked further into the Timer class and decided to go with [System Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) as it proved to be better with a longer function.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should look into the Windows Forms [Timer class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx). You don't want a loop in your main form. It's better to use the timer to fire events which can be processed asynchronously on another thread.

Comment: This seems to be what I'm looking for.  One question though.  Is this going to lock the UI while the timer function is being performed?

Comment: The UI can get locked any time you try to access a control from another thread. Get familiar with the InvokeRequired property, and check out MethodInvoker http://www.csharper.net/blog/methodinvoker___anonymous_methods___teh_r0x0r.aspx

Answer (score 1):

(I assume this is a winform application)

Invoking on the main thread is the way to go. But what about using a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) instead of an endless loop? It gives you more control. And a the timer function would execute on it's own thread.

It's good practice to let long going work execute on a background thread, so that the main thread can work with the UI.